# how to define a constant array in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, constants

How to define constant 1 or 2 dimensional array in C/C++?
I deal with embedded platform (Xilinx EDK), so the resources are limited.

I'd like to write in third-party header file something like

```
#define MYCONSTANT 5
```

but for array. Like

```
#define MYARRAY(index) { 5, 6, 7, 8 }
```

What is the most common way to do this?

Comment: A macro based solution as used in the first example wouldn't work. Somewhere, an actual array must be allocated in memory, as in sbi's answer

Comment: Please elaborate a bit. Does constant array mean that you don't want the array to be changed at a later stage or something else.

Comment: @Aditya Kumar - that's correct. I want to define the set of constants in separate file(s) and access them using integer index from main source file.

Comment: Then @jahhaj's answer seems to be the most appropriate

Comment: The Xilinx tag isn't going to help you.  I would suggest dropping it, and adding "const" and "array" tags, although at this point the question has been answered sufficiently anyway.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In C++ source file

```
extern "C" const int array[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

In header file to be included in both C and C++ source file

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
extern const int array[];
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 33):

In C++, the most common way to define a constant array should certainly be to, erm, *define a constant array*:

```
const int my_array[] = {5, 6, 7, 8};
```

Do you have any reason to assume that there would be some problem on that embedded platform?

Comment: okay. And where to define it - header/source file? 
When i define it in third-party h file (it's a separate driver for microprocessor system) - i get an error - something like "this variable cannot be defined multiple times".

Comment: when i define it in source file - it cannot be accessed from main.cc file (in which i include mydriver.h)

Comment: So you are writing in C? You have managed to pick on the the few areas where  the same code will work differently in C and C++, so please specify which language

Comment: in source file const int array[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; in header file extern const int array[]; you need both (assuming you are writing C)

Comment: yes, external h/source files are in C and main source code is in C++ - that is the way EDK offers to do

Comment: Well that's another complication. Mixed C and C++ means you are also going to need extern "C" declarations, see the new answer I added

Answer (score 8):

In C++

```
const int array[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

That was easy enough but maybe I'm not understanding your question correctly. The above will not work in C however, please specify what language you are really interested in. There is no such language as C/C++.

Comment: Why doesn't this work in C? I thought C had copied `const` from C++ by, I think C89?

Comment: If this was put in a header file and that header file was included in more than one source file, in C you would get multiple definition errors, in C++ you would not. Const does not have exactly the same meaning in C and C++.

Comment: to be specific - my application consists in general of 2 parts - main program written in C++ and peripheral core software driver written in pure C (as it is compiled as a part of board support package).

Comment: @jahhaj: Thanks! I never really worked in C, so I didn't know that.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to define `array` constant using the define directive.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem. In my case, I needed an array of constants in order to use as size of other static arrays. When I tried to use the

```
const int my_const_array[size] = {1, 2, 3, ... };
```

and then declare:

```
int my_static_array[my_const_array[0]];
```

I get an error from my compiler:

```
array bound is not an integer constant
```

So, finally I did the following (Maybe there are more elegant ways to do that):

```
#define element(n,d) ==(n) ? d :
#define my_const_array(i) (i) element(0,1) (i) element(1,2) (i) element(2,5) 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#define defStrs new string[4] { "str1","str2","str3","str4" }
using namespace std;
...

const string * strs = defStrs;
string ezpzStr = strs[0] + "test" + strs[1];

cout << ezpzStr << endl;
```

Took me a while to figure this out, but apparently it works like this in C++.
Works on *my* computer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Only try to understand what the compiler does. When it finds the HASHTAG , it replaces its content into the place where it's writed. So for example, if u do this:

#define MYARRAY { 5, 6, 7, 8 }

byte list[] = MYARRAY ;

You will get it in the array 'list' . Another way to get the same result is:

#define MYARRAY 5, 6, 7, 8

byte list[] = {MYARRAY} ;

In conclusion, the compliler what does is 'cutting' the hashtag and 'pasting' the content of it. I hope I had solved your doubt